# Displaying an info message above mail body in gmail

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I've been trying to display some text over each mail, using google's app script. For example, for spam emails, gmail shows an infobox as below:
[image]

I want to show something similar for each mail, for example, a message saying, you've never received an email from this user, or anything else. Can this be achieved using app script?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get this exact interface. Your best bet is to follow this [the guide about extending the Gmail's message UI with a Workspace Add-on](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/gmail/extending-message-ui). Not sure if it will be good enough for what you are trying to do.